# Devart Oracle stored procedure performance issue

Tags: asp.net, oracle, performance, plsql, devart

There is a performance problem about executing stored procedures in Oracle.

Procedure's name is : `myutil_api.move`

- Plsql executes this procedure in 0.2 sec.
- Web App executes this procedure in 30 secs.

Same users, same procedures but there is huge different.

(Web app and plsql executes other procedures with no problem and same time)

Devart Connect Oracle code:

```
var db = new F8Connection();

using (db)
{
    using (var command = new OracleCommand())
    {
        db.Open();
        command.Connection = db;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "myutil_api.move";
        command.ParameterCheck = true;
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("BARCODE_ID_", OracleDbType.Number)).Value = part.BarcodeId;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: @APC no, Network is just fine so i can't figure out why.

Comment: The time is going somewhere. It's not the database and (you assert) it's not the network. So your only hope is to trace the call through the whole stack. How well is your code instrumented? Are you allowed to use Wireshark?

Comment: Please provide the following information via https://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html : 1) the DDL/DML script for creating your stored procedure and related database objects; 2) your connection string (mark confidential information with asterisks); 3) the version of your Oracle Server and Oracle Client